Physical Interpreting Enthalpy as a state function
At constant pressure, the change in enthalpy (ΔH) is equal to the heat added to or removed from the system (ΔQ). However, for processes involving variable pressure, this relationship becomes more complex. In such cases, what does the change in enthalpy actually represent physically?
Does it reflect the change in the system's energy content, or is it primarily useful as a state function for convenience as it serves a practical role in calculations of quantities such as those involving Gibbs free energy to determine the spontaneity of a process?

In an adiabatic open system flow process like a turbine, the shaft work is equal to the change in enthalpy.

Note that Gibbs energy change determines spontaneity at constant pressure as well. Similarly, Helmholtz energy change for constant volume.

First things first: please note that $\Delta Q$, in the context where you are using it, has no meaning, given that $Q$ is not a state function. Note, in particular, that $Q$ has the meaning of heat transfer between different states of a system or between different subsystems.
It is however possible to define a $\Delta Q$ with meaning of difference in heat flows in experimental techniques like DSC (Differential Scanning Calorimetry), even thought as my personal choice I would avoid this notation.
Now, to address your question: if you consider an equilibrium process with variable pressure, you have that $$H=H(S,p)=U+pV$$
Then this means that:
$$\text{d}H=\text{d}U+p\text{d}V + V\text{d}p=\delta q +\delta w +p\text{d}V + V\text{d}p$$
Let us assume that there is no extra work (no chemical reactions, no diffusion, no electrochemical gradients, no elastic work, nothing outside of mechanical pressure-volume work):
$$\text{d}H=\delta q -p\text{d}V+p\text{d}V + V\text{d}p=\delta q +V\text{d}p$$
But, assuming an equilibrium process (and only in this case this holds):
$$\text{d}S=\frac{\delta q_{ \ rev}}{T} \implies \text{d}H=T\text{d}S +V\text{d}p$$
We call $S$ and $p$ the "natural variables" of $H$ in the sense that they arise naturally by analyzing the differential form associated to Enthalpy. From this differential form, we can deduce various things:

As, you say, if there is no pressure change, the differential of Enthalpy coincides with the reversible $\delta q$ and thus there is an extremum principle you can deduce by considering:
$$\text{d}H=T\text{d}S\geq0$$
Even if there is a certain pressure change, if the process is isoentropic the enthalpy gives you an indirect measure of the expansion work.
If the process is neither pressure, nor entropically constant, then you cannot deduce (in a simple and general way) an extremum principle for enthalpy.

One important thing to notice is that althought it is natural to define theoreticaly $H=H(S,p)$, there is absolutely no need to assume that those are the only possible variables, as a matter of fact, we know that enthalpy depends on temperature, thus it is possible to express $H=H(T,p)$.
Unfortunately, though, this formulation does not give us any clue to determine if a process is spontaneous, but it does give us some nice informations:
$$H(T,p)\implies \text{d}H=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p\text{d}T+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)_T\text{d}p$$
We define $\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p$ as the Specific Heat at constant pressure $C_p$, a really important property of matter, because it tells us the value of the derivative of Entropy with respect to temperature at constant pressure. I will prove it in the following.
We know that $G=H-TS$ and it is true that $H=G+TS$ and so:
$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_p +S(T,p)+T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p =S-S+T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p$$
The entropy terms cancel out to give:
$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p=C_p=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p \implies \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p = \frac{C_p}{T}$$
You could do similar tricks to obtain a form for the other partial derivative and you would find a relation between the derivative of $H$ with respect to pressure at constant temperature, wich is not trivial and depends on volume, temperature and the coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha$.

you wrote " please note that ΔQ has no meaning", $\Delta Q$ is a calorimetrically measurable quantity, what more meaning in physics you expect a quantity, any quantity, to have?

I meant in the context of his statement. Maybe I should make it clearer. In calorimetry $\Delta Q$ has a meaning because heat flows are measured relative to one another and it makes sense.

Added an edit to address your issue, thanks!
